# screen change with a presence detector

Tags: pi-4, sensor, screen

in relation to the change of application / screen from a terminal, my idea is that in "rest" a kitten is seen, and when a presence sensor detects activity, a policeman appears asking for stop.

I have been looking for information but I have come to turn on and off a led, but I can not make a change between files or between different desktops.

My main idea is to do it with a Rpi4b.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to do ... are you trying to display graphics that are dependent on some type of input?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @jsotola Can you tell me what you need to know?